# How to map a navigational property to a table where it isn't a key column?

Tags: entity-framework

I have an Entity like:

```
User
   Id
   Username
   public virtual List<String> CountryNames { get;set; }
```

And it has a property for CountryNames as seen above, and this is linked to another table but it isn't linked on a key column.

The CountryNames property should get all UserCountry rows that have the Username.

```
UserCountry
  Id
  CountrName
  Username
```

How can I configure the User model to do this?

I realize this is bad design, I'm not looking for schema design advise at this point as it is out of my hands.

I'm using EF6.